# Use of transistor for switching the led

Tags: transistors, ldr

I have been trying a lot to get my circuit work. I want the led to light up when the LDR receives no light and vice versa. I have found that the LDR offers the resistance of approximately 6k ohms when light is exposed on it and 66k ohms when light is not exposed to it. So I have used the resistors with those value. But I am not being able to achieve it [image]in the simulator. Also there is glowing of the led in which lesser current is flowing but there is no glowing when more current is flowing. Please point out my mistakes and suggest me to get my circuit work.
I want the current to flow through the transistor "only" when there is light exposed to the LDR (possibly by keeping the low resistance for this path compared to the closed path of the LED). And when there is darkness, the current should not flow through the transistor leaving only a single path for the current to pass i.e. through the LED. Thanks for the help.

**edit:**  The source in the collector circuit needs a ground return. Why is it so?

Comment: You should probably use an opamp in a comparator configuration and feed the output of that into the transistor that should be configured as a switch

Comment: would you please explain further?\

Comment: The base-emitter circuit and collector circuit are totally independent.

Comment: but there is a role of base voltage for letting the current through the transistor. Isn't it @Chu?

Comment: The source in the collector circuit needs a ground return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not disconnect your powersupply's ground connection with the transistor. The way you draw it the LED is connected to a closed loop that is not really affected by the state of the transistor. 
So schematic wise you're probably looking for something like this.

Component values give roughly 15 mA LED current.

Idrive ~= (V2 - Vbe_Q1)/R1 ~= (1.5-0.6)/1000 = 0.9 mA.
I_LED ~= (V1 - V_D1)/R1 = (9-3)/390 = 15 mA.
Use lower value of R1 for more current.

[image: schematic]

Comment: The downvoter does not understand how to vote properly. If downvoting an answer like this one, which addresses the main fault with the original circuit, a downvoter MUST say why - as otherwise they make it seem like the answer is fundamentally wrong - which is not the case. Downvoting in this manner is about equivalent to trolling.

Comment: I'm neither an upvoter nor a downvoter, but looking at the edit history it looks like the original schematic didn't make much sense unless you read the fine-print. The right way to show that the values doesn't mean anything is to _leave them out_, not just write anything random and hope that people won't try to build it.

Comment: As per my understanding, the current doesnt flow until the circuit is closed. For closing the circuit, the base voltage must exceed the breakdown voltage (0.7V). Here, the LDR(5k & 66k resistor in the schematic) is used to limit the voltage. When the LDR offers 5k resistance, base voltage exceeds the breakdown voltage due to which the current flows through the transistor (less resistive path). But when the resistance offered by LDR is 66k, the current cant flow through the transistor which leaves only the path through the LED to complete the circuit.Is anything wrong with my understanding?

Comment: Not exactly... you have a diode in the base emitter path of your transistor which has a forward voltage of 0.7V - so it's not the breakdown voltage. What your LDR does is controlling the current going into the base ((1.5V-0.7V)/RLDR) which is then amplified by factor B... so IC = B * IB. So there will always be some current (probably negligable with high base resistor) trough the transistor.

Comment: Thats the thing I was missing. So if I keep the source voltage below 0.7, there will be no any current through the transistor and I can get my led lit up. Right? Wait, doesnt the LDR function as the voltage divider like the resistor does?

Comment: Dividing what voltage?

Comment: some portion of the voltage applied is dropped across the resistor. Doesnt this happen in case of LDR?

Comment: It's not "some" portion... it will always be V-0.7V. This means if your transistor has a B of 1000 and you have 1.5V with a 66k resistor the collector current will be (1.5V-0.7V)/66k*1000=12mA